# Workaround for IE10 setInterval Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

During testing of our Javascript library I think we found a severe memory leak in IE10's (v10.0.9200.16519 - Windows 8 64 bit) Javascript implementation of `setInterval`.

A simple test case showed that if a variable is captured in the closure of the function being passed as the argument for later execution it does not seem to ever become eligible for garbage collection, i.e. the browser still seems to hold a reference to the function or at least the closure variables.

Our testcase executes the `setInterval` function only once and then clears the interval timer, i.e. after a while no code is running anymore and no variables are accessible anymore (as far as I can see no globals are introduced in this code, except for the method to run in `onload`), nevertheless the process takes up half a gigabyte of memory (depending on the number of iterations).

Interestingly this does not happen if we use the `setTimeout` method instead (and also the problem does *not* seem to exist in IE9, and current versions of Chrome, FF).

The problem can be seen with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbpwp/).

Run it in a fresh instance of IE10 on Windows 8 and open the task manager to watch the memory usage. It will grow quickly to 350 Megabytes and will stay there after the script was executed.

This is the important part of the problematic code piece:

```
// the function that when called multiple times will cause the leak in IE10
var eatMemory = function() {
    var a = null; // the captured closure variable
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
       a = createBigArray(); // call a method that allocates a lot of memory
       clearInterval(intervalId); // stop the interval timer
    }, 100);
}
```

(I know that it is easy to fix *this specific* piece of code. But that's not the point - this is just the tiniest piece of code we came up with that reproduces the problem. The real code actually captures `this` in the closure and that object is never garbage collected.)

Is there a bug in our code or is there a way to use `setInterval` where a closure variable holds a reference to a large object without triggering the memory leak and without reverting to "recursive" `setTimeout` calls?

(I also [posted the question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/c44421e8-26ff-4d8e-900e-dcae639f6999))

**Update:** This issue also exists in IE10 on Windows 7, but does not exist if you switch to IE9-standards mode. I submitted this to MS Connect and will report progress.

**Update:** Microsoft [accepted the issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783448/major-memory-leak-in-ie10s-javascript-setinterval-implementation) and reported it to be fixed in IE11 (preview version) - I haven't confirmed this myself, yet (anybody?)

**Update:** IE 11 has been officially released and I cannot reproduce the problem on that version with my system (Win 8.1 Pro 64bit) anymore.

Comment: Why are you creating an interval and then clearing it immediately? Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @BradM I updated the question with an explanation - the real code is more complicated than that and does not always unconditionally clear the interval.

Comment: Have you tried not using an anonymous function, but a function reference instead – and afterwards explicitly overwriting this reference?

Comment: "this does not happen if we use the setTimeout method instead" - so, problem solved, then? Anything you can do with setInterval you can do via repeated setTimeout calls, right?

Comment: @MarkBessey Yes, and no :-) My code can be made to work, yes, but the actual problem (the leak) is not solved. Sure, I can rewrite the `setInterval` implementation - I would rather understand the problem in my code (if there is one) or have it fixed in IE, of course. The more attention this problem gets, the more likely it will be fixed and the fewer people will be affected in the future. So I hate to call the problem "solved", although the way it looks right now, I am going to do exactly that.

Comment: @CBroe I need the closure aspect (capturing the outer variable), so I am not sure whether you mean the same thing - I tried http://jsfiddle.net/jbpwp/2/ - go play with the fiddle and modify it if you mean something else!

Comment: Can confirm your IEssue... Where Chrome needs 6MB, Firefox 40MB, IE burns up to 400MB. Doing `a = undefined` in the end of f, it gets collected. I also recommend to use setTimeout to re-call something. The 'term' interval is misleading, because the fn never happens in, for or after at least n ms.

Comment: Interestingly you can't anymore delete a var (as they specified in specs), so it really only gets collected if you set `a` to null (or undefined as I prefer in jS). That said, in your second fiddle `delete f` returns false and doesn't cleanup f.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For completeness sake I am adding a possible workaround here:

As I have already written (and commenters suggested), this can be worked around (not fixed) by falling back to `setTimeout`. This is not trivial, since some id book-keeping needs to be done. Here is my suggested fix, that you can [test and fork from this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGuy/mDCB6/):

```
var registerSetIntervalFix = function(){
    var _setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    var _clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
    window.setInterval = function(fn, interval){
        var recurse = function(){
            var newId = _setTimeout(recurse, interval);
            window.setInterval.mapping[returnValue] = newId;
            fn();
        }
        var id = _setTimeout(recurse, interval);
        var returnValue = id;
        while (window.setInterval.mapping[returnValue]){
            returnValue++;
        }
        window.setInterval.mapping[returnValue] = id;
        return returnValue;
    }
    window.setInterval.mapping = {};
    window.clearInterval = function(id){
        var realId = window.setInterval.mapping[id];
        _clearTimeout(realId);
        delete window.setInterval.mapping[id];
    }
}
```

The idea is to recursively call `setTimeout` to simulate recurring `setInterval` calls. There is a little overhead in this implementation since it has to perform the bookkeeping for the changing `id`s, so I wouldn't recommend applying this fix unless it is required.

Unfortunately I am not able to come up with a "feature" detection algorithm (more like a "bug"-detection algorithm), so I guess you have to revert to good old browser detection. Also my implementation cannot deal with strings as the first argument and does not pass additional arguments to the inner function. Lastly it is not safe to call this method twice, so use it at your own risk (and feel free to improve it)!

(Note: For our library we will stop using `setInterval` from now and instead rewrite the few parts in the code that rely on it to use `setTimeout` directly.)