# Script not working properly in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, setinterval

I'm using the following code to grab some data out of an SQL database. It works fine in all browsers, bar IE10. It updates once and then just holds onto the initial value. It doesn't change when the value in the database changes.

```
setInterval(function turkey () {

    jQuery('#lat_grabber').load('mapReloadLat.php');
    jQuery('#lng_grabber').load('mapReloadLong.php');
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905652/workaround-for-ie10-setinterval-memory-leak), maybe can help

Comment: Thanks ... what do you mean by "pass a variable that changes into the call"??

Comment: A variable that changes the call: `jQuery('#lat_grabber').load('mapReloadLat.php', {nonce: (new Date()).getMilliseconds()});`

Answer (score 2):

Your AJAX request is very likely getting serviced from the cache (you could use Fiddler to verify).

To workaround this, I'd change the load to a jQuery.ajax call, that way you can set the cache property to false.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "mapReloadLat.php",
    cache: false,
    complete: function (data) {
        jQuery('#lat_grabber').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, IE will almost invariably cache ajax requests unless you use cache: false (which appends a random query string argument) or unless you very carefully set the headers to prevent caching (and then clear your cache so IE has to pull the new version with the no-cache headers)