# Reason to clearInterval before window unload?

Tags: javascript, browser, compatibility, setinterval

I've noticed in a couple of JavaScript libraries that make use of `setInterval`, that the library will bind an event listener to the `window`'s `unload` event, so as to clear all the created intervals using `clearInterval`.

One example is History.js which keeps a ["List of intervals set, to be cleared when document is unloaded"](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/6c6c8b951b03fa725adb11b1087d73b0b6f0ac82/scripts/uncompressed/history.js#L152-L173).

**Snippet:**

```
// ====================================================================
// Interval record

/**
 * History.intervalList
 * List of intervals set, to be cleared when document is unloaded.
 */
History.intervalList = [];

/**
 * History.clearAllIntervals
 * Clears all setInterval instances.
 */
History.clearAllIntervals = function(){
    var i, il = History.intervalList;
    if (typeof il !== "undefined" && il !== null) {
        for (i = 0; i < il.length; i++) {
            clearInterval(il[i]);
        }
        History.intervalList = null;
    }
};
```

The event listener that calls this function on the `unload` event is added [here](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/6c6c8b951b03fa725adb11b1087d73b0b6f0ac82/scripts/uncompressed/history.js#L1907-L1910).

**Snippet:**

```
/**
 * Clear Intervals on exit to prevent memory leaks
 */
History.Adapter.bind(window,"unload",History.clearAllIntervals);
```

So, my question is, why do some JavaScript authors do this? It seems like these intervals will be cleared automatically when the browsers leaves the page (I've never seen it do otherwise). Is there an advantage to doing this? Does it compensate for a browser bug of some kind? If so, what bug and which browsers does it affect?

Comment: Interesting question if there is a valid reason to do this. I don't see one though.

Comment: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/commit/91a5c5bcd63cb5fc35e786de3a11218ea69e65bc

Comment: Why not contact the authors of history.js, their emails are at the bottom of https://github.com/browserstate/history.js (though the above comment seems like it has to do with some sort of dependency on Env.js)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty It's my understanding that the original author of History.js no longer maintains it and hasn't for a while, and I assumed it must be a bug that is not exclusive to History.js. I'm still curious as to what the bug(?) with Env.js is.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: does it really matter? Another library requires that for some reason.

Comment: @zerkms Sure. I create JavaScript libraries sometimes. If there's a valid reason to do this, then I'd like to know what it is, rather than blindly follow what another developer is doing.

Comment: No valid reason to do this. End. Of. Story.

Comment: @self Evidently not, if headless-browser Env.js has a bug this fixes. It's debatable if you should support Env.js, but if you need to support Env.js, then there is a valid reason.

Comment: Cleaning up event binding is not necessary in this situation, but it could also be thought of as good practice, and may help stop memory leaks in old browsers.

Comment: @macguru2000: you are leaving a page. Why would you care about leaks when the runtime is about to be destroyed?

Comment: @zerkms, I agree with you in principle, but I also don't code the browsers, and can't always assume they behave correctly. Have you worked with Internet Explorer 6? Even modern Chrome is buggy.

Comment: @macguru2000: then you probably `null` **all the references** as far as you have done working with them, do you?

Comment: Hahaha, no, was just saying there is some validity too it, especially with event bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [this code was added to History.js for compatibility with Env.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/commit/91a5c5bcd63cb5fc35e786de3a11218ea69e65bc).

Env.js is a headless browser written in JavaScript that is no longer under active development. So this is definitely an edge-case, to say the least. I'm guessing this issue is caused by a limitation of JavaScript itself.

User Lance Leonard has pointed out in the comments that there is a [possible memory leak issue in IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905652/workaround-for-ie10-setinterval-memory-leak/15919452).

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905652/workaround-for-ie10-setinterval-memory-leak/15919452#15919452?